# How do you apply an effect on image that makes the image slide in the page?

Tags: html, css, image

I was wondering how to apply some effect on images. And not directly on the image but as we scroll down the page. For example, when you scroll down, the images fade in or they slide in from the side of the page. I came across skrollr but not sure if it's the right library.

Anyone knows how?

Comment: It maybe worth looking at the jQuery plugin --> [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). Here's an [Example](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html)

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Giving the image an effect and building a trigger on a scroll event are different issues. Take a look at inview js plugin as an event. Then add a class to the image element with the ending animation placement.

Comment: Check this out: http://codepen.io/jdsteinbach/pen/FbBDt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I came across skrollr but not sure if it's the right library.

Given your requirements: yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Search for **Parallax Effect**

[For example](http://richardshepherd.com/smashing/parallax/)

[Other Examples with Source and Demo](http://www.desiznworld.com/2013/07/free-jquery-parallax-scrolling-plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to acheive the desired fading. On would be a backgroundColor-clear transparent gradient png image that the images slide into view from(behind the png). Our you could apply style transformations based on the x or y coordinates of an image with some javascript, and smooth the effects by using transitions in CSS3. I am sure there are a 50 different ways that similar effects could be used with jQuery.
Was there something specific you had in mind? or are you just wanting a recommendation?

Comment: I was thinking, as you scroll down, the image pops out from the side. You go down and the image comes from the side of your screen and stay there afterwards.

Comment: So you want some sort of event listener, using something like scrollTop to activate a div moving into position, with a CSS transition to smooth out the animation. Would you need the image simply float in place? or become a part of the page layout and scroll with the page?

Comment: Yeah exactly. I would need it to become part of the page and not scroll with the page.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is your best bet. First add a reference to jQuery, and then jQuery UI:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then go to http://jqueryui.com/ and read the references. It's very easy >8).

I also have to mention that jQuery is very widely used within the corporate world, so learning it will improve your skill-set with a great tool

Answer (score 0):

[this question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149700/how-to-move-animate-elements-in-from-the-side-with-stellar-js-on-a-vertical-scro)

You can achieve this kind of effects using the above Stellar js effects

or this might well help - using Jquery Scroll path.

http://joelb.me/scrollpath/