# Horizontal position movement on vertical scroll Stellar JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, parallax

I am having difficulty with my horizontal offset effect. I want to use only Stellar JS to horizontally shift an **img** on vertical scroll. As of now, I have a container element that's 1800px tall and an **img** inside whose height & width are dynamically set on load (based on viewport... ie it's height is the height of the viewport and the width is proportionally wider than the viewport).

When scrolling vertically from the top of the container to the bottom of the container, I want the **img** to slide left from it's left edge all the way to its right edge. Therefore, at the top of the container, the **img** will be aligned left and overflowing right, and then at the bottom of the container, the **img** will be aligned right and overflowing left.

Here is an example created by the Stellar JS creator that is close to what (but with some unwanted vertical scroll as well) --> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149700/how-to-move-animate-elements-in-from-the-side-with-stellar-js-on-a-vertical-scro)

Take a look at this template jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z6F3h/2/ It needs to have the effect implemented. I believe that I need to modify... `setTop` and `setLeft` properties

Answer (score 2):

The creator of the stellar.js plugin gave a great foundation over here for making it move horizontally and vertically at the same time.

[How to move/animate elements in from the side with Stellar.js on a vertical scroll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149700/how-to-move-animate-elements-in-from-the-side-with-stellar-js-on-a-vertical-scro)

If you're looking for the layer to only move horizontally and not up and down AT ALL, then I modified his code slightly to have the top stay the same.

http://jsfiddle.net/QGd9g/995/

The modifications I made were to have originalTop - newTop, instead of just setting top to be the new Top.

```
$(function(){
    $.stellar.positionProperty.apple = {
        setTop: function($el, newTop, originalTop) {
            $el.css({
                'top': originalTop - newTop,
                'left': $el.hasClass('apple') ? originalTop - newTop : 0
            });
        }
    };

    $.stellar({
        verticalOffset: 200,
        horizontalScrolling: false,
        positionProperty: 'apple'
    });
});
```

What's tricky about what I did (there might be a better solution), is that you setLeft, and the layer will move to the right.

Comment: Can I use that on background somehow?