# jquery div move horizontally and vertically when scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have 2 groups of divs cross each other vertically and horizontally when I scroll down my page.

Here is what I have down for the vertical part.
http://tes-stellar.freeiz.com/
All codes are available in the source code. 
It may appear huge on some screens.

Now i'm trying to make the red square go from left to right and cross the word "original".

I tried with the "apple" trick from Mark Dalgleish 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149700/how-to-move-animate-elements-in-from-the-side-with-stellar-js-on-a-vertical-scro)
but my 3 JS scripts are blocking it.

I have this in js.js

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

$(window).stellar();

var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');

slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }

    else {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }

});

mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});

function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}

links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});


});
```

The code above is supposed to be for another part of my website (the parallax backgrounds, but blocks the effect I want to give to the red square, which is

```
<body>

<div class="vertical-offset"></div>
<div class="horizontal-offset"></div>

<h2 data-stellar-offset-parent="true">
<div id="original" >
<div class="o-1 part-original" data-stellar-ratio="-2.4"></div>
<div class="o-2 part-original" data-stellar-ratio="2.4"></div>

<!-- many other lines, then -->

<!-- the red square is next -->
<div class="apple" data-stellar-ratio="1"></div>

</div>
</h2>

</body>
```

I'd like to know if someone had any advice or if my code is completely wrong.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: you could consider adding a Simple example of code that include parts of the code that you are in trouble otherwhise people here will be down voting your question without any suggestion.

Comment: @ecarrizo thanks for the tip, it is now done.